# How to substring based on a list of start end arrays

Tags: java

I have a String and an associated List of a custom object. Each custom object in the List contains a *start* and *end* character for some information in the String. I want to process the String in such a way that I skip over the characters in the String that fall within the bounds defined by the List of custom objects. The translated string will then be reconstructed such that the characters defined by the List of custom objects are including, untranslated, in the new String. I have previously ordered the List of custom objects based on *start* character so can be confident that I can iterate through the List.

Currently I do something like this. But am wondering if there is a better, more efficient way to do this?

```
private static String translateString(String input, List listOfStartEnds) {
    int postition = 0;
    String translated = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < listOfStartEnds.size(); i++) {
        String sub = input.substring(postition, listOfStartEnds.get(i).getStart());
        // Calls an HTTP Post to translate a string and attempts to reconstruct
        translated += TranslateHelper.translate(sub) + " " + input.statusText.substring(listOfStartEnds.get(i).getStart(), listOfStartEnds.get(i).getEnd()) + " ";  
        postition = listOfStartEnds.get(i).getEnd();
    }
    return translated;
}
```

Comment: You can use StringBuilder to avoid constructing the intermediate values of `translated`.

Comment: Thanks @AndyTurner, will refactor my code later on and post an update, but is there is still the problem of how to make the rest of the code more efficient. Help is always appreciated.

Comment: Other than using `StringBuilder` and pulling `listOfStarts.get(i)` into a variable to avoid repeated lookup (or using an enhanced for loop), I don't think there is much more you can do to make it "efficient".

Comment: To put this another way, what is the perceived inefficiency?

Comment: @AndyTurner Good question, I guess it's lack of understanding of what is possible. My computing theory ended with a few basic data structures, primitives, and simple loops. So I don't know if there are better built in ways of doing certain things. By more efficient I mean something more suited to the task. The StringBuilder is a classic example. I never knew it existed and was used to concating my strings because that's all I knew. Cheers for your help!